# Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I have written foll query but getting error:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ;
Following is the stored procedure query
I know its the syntax error but cannot figure out where exactly the problem is.
It will be a great help if someone help me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MCSIL_HR.sp_ins_emp_mst_DEV (
   inemp_id                    emp_mst.emp_id%TYPE,
   inemp_restrict_emp          emp_mst.restrict_emp%TYPE,
   inemp_name                  emp_mst.emp_name%TYPE,
   inemp_email                 emp_mst.email_id%TYPE,
   inemp_pwd                   emp_mst.emp_pwd%TYPE,
   indob                       VARCHAR2,
   indoj                       VARCHAR2,
   indor                       VARCHAR2,
   inemp_status_lkp_id         emp_mst.emp_status_lkp_id%TYPE,
   inemp_has_reportee_status   emp_mst.has_reportees_status_yn%TYPE,
   inupd_emp_id                emp_mst.emp_id%TYPE,
   inupd_flag                  CHAR,
   indept                       VARCHAR2,
   inmgr_id          emp_mst.mgr_id%TYPE,                   
   outmsg                OUT   VARCHAR2,
   outstatus             OUT   VARCHAR2
)
IS

   pgm_error   EXCEPTION;
   as_emp_id   emp_mst.emp_id%TYPE;
   as_cnt      NUMBER;
   upd_flag    VARCHAR2 (3);
   asdob       DATE;
   asdoj       DATE;
   asdor       DATE;


BEGIN

   outmsg := '';
   outstatus := 'TRUE';
   upd_flag := UPPER (TRIM (inupd_flag));
-- check if Emp Status lookup value exists in lookup table , if not raise error
   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO as_cnt
     FROM lookup l
    WHERE l.lkp_id = inemp_status_lkp_id;
   IF as_cnt = 0
   THEN
      outmsg :=
            'Employee Sattus LOOK UP VALUE : '
         || TO_CHAR (inemp_status_lkp_id)
         || ' NOT EXISTS IN LOOKUP TABLE ';
      outstatus := 'INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE Failed.';
      RAISE pgm_error;
   END IF;
-- check if Yes/No Status ookup value exists in lookup table , if not raise error
   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO as_cnt
     FROM lookup l
    WHERE l.lkp_id = inemp_has_reportee_status;
   IF as_cnt = 0
   THEN
      outmsg :=
            'Has_Reportees Status LOOK UP VALUE : '
         || TO_CHAR (inemp_has_reportee_status)
         || ' NOT EXISTS IN LOOKUP TABLE ';
      outstatus := 'INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE Failed.';
      RAISE pgm_error;
   END IF;
-- check whether user modifying data is valid employee
   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO as_cnt
     FROM emp_mst e
    WHERE e.emp_id = inupd_emp_id;
   IF as_cnt = 0
   THEN
      outmsg :=
            'UPDATING USER ID: '
         || TO_CHAR (inupd_emp_id)
         || ' NOT EXISTS IN EMPLOYEE MASTER ';
      outstatus := 'INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE Failed.';
      RAISE pgm_error;
   END IF;
   -- checking date formatt (dd-mm-yyyy)
   IF    indob IS NULL
      OR NOT (    SUBSTR (TRIM (indob), 3, 1) = '-'
              AND SUBSTR (TRIM (indob), 6, 1) = '-'
             )
   THEN
      outmsg :=
         'Date of Birth is Blank or Formatt for Date of Birth is not in DD-MM-YYYY, Contact Administrator';
      outstatus := 'INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE Failed.';
      RAISE pgm_error;
   END IF;
   IF    indoj IS NULL
      OR NOT (    SUBSTR (TRIM (indoj), 3, 1) = '-'
              AND SUBSTR (TRIM (indoj), 6, 1) = '-'
             )
   THEN
      outmsg :=
         'Date of Join is Blank or Formatt for Date of Join is not in DD-MM-YYYY, Contact Administrator';
      outstatus := 'INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE Failed.';
      RAISE pgm_error;
   END IF;
   IF     indor IS NOT NULL
      AND NOT (    SUBSTR (TRIM (indor), 3, 1) = '-'
               AND SUBSTR (TRIM (indor), 6, 1) = '-'
              )
   THEN
      outmsg :=
         'Formatt for Date of Resign is not in DD-MM-YYYY, Contact Administrator';
      outstatus := 'INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE Failed.';
      RAISE pgm_error;
   END IF;
   asdob := TO_DATE (TRIM (indob), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
   asdoj := TO_DATE (TRIM (indoj), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
   asdor := TO_DATE (TRIM (indor), 'DD-MM-YYYY');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'LKP SRNO, UPDATE USER EMPCODE OK,'
                         || 'DOB :'
                         || TO_CHAR (asdob)
                         || ',DOJ :'
                         || TO_CHAR (asdoj)
                         || ',DOR :'
                         || TO_CHAR (asdor)
                        );
-- check whether user modifying data is valid employee
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO as_cnt
     FROM emp_mst e
    WHERE e.emp_id = inemp_id;
   IF upd_flag = 'U'
   THEN
      IF as_cnt = 0
      THEN
         outmsg :=
               'EMPLOYEE CODE : '
            || TO_CHAR (inemp_id)
            || ' NOT EXISTS IN EMPLOYEE MASTER';
         outstatus := 'UPDATE Failed.';
         RAISE pgm_error;
      END IF;
      UPDATE emp_mst a
         SET a.rec_dtl = rec_dtl (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
       WHERE a.rec_dtl IS NULL;
-- For password change call another procedure
      UPDATE emp_mst a
         SET a.emp_name = inemp_name,
             a.restrict_emp = inemp_restrict_emp,                               
             a.email_id=inemp_email,                                            
 a.emp_pwd = ENCRYPT(inemp_pwd),
             a.dob = asdob,
             a.doj = asdoj,
             a.dor = asdor,
             a.emp_status_lkp_id = inemp_status_lkp_id,
             a.has_reportees_status_yn = inemp_has_reportee_status,             
             a.rec_dtl.updated_by = inupd_emp_id,
             a.DEPT=  indept,
         a.MGR_ID = inmgr_id,               
             a.rec_dtl.updated_on = SYSDATE 
       WHERE a.emp_id = inemp_id;
      IF SQLCODE <> 0
      THEN
         ROLLBACK;
         outstatus := 'FALSE';
         outmsg := 'UPDATE Failed.';
         RAISE pgm_error;
      ELSE
         COMMIT;
         outstatus := 'TRUE';
         outmsg := 'Process sucessfully executed';
      END IF;
   ELSIF upd_flag = 'I'
   THEN
      IF as_cnt > 0
      THEN
         outmsg :=
               'EMPLOYEE ID : '
            || TO_CHAR (inemp_id)
            || ' ALREADY IN EMPLOYEE MASTER';
         outstatus := 'INSERT Failed.';
         RAISE pgm_error;
      END IF;
      INSERT INTO mcsil_hr.emp_mst
                  (emp_id,restrict_emp, emp_name,email_id, emp_pwd, dob, doj, dor,              ---added by shailesh 
                   emp_status_lkp_id, has_reportees_status_yn,
                   rec_dtl,DEPT,MGR_ID
                  )
           VALUES (inemp_id,inemp_restrict_emp, inemp_name, inemp_email, ENCRYPT(inemp_pwd), asdob, asdoj, asdor,  ---added by shailesh 
                   inemp_status_lkp_id, inemp_has_reportee_status,
                   rec_dtl (inupd_emp_id, SYSDATE, NULL, NULL),indept,inmgr_id     
                  );
      IF SQLCODE <> 0
      THEN
         ROLLBACK;
         outstatus := 'FALSE';
         outmsg := 'INSERT Failed.';
         RAISE pgm_error;
      ELSE
         COMMIT;
         outstatus := 'TRUE';
         outmsg := 'Process Sucessfully executed';
      END IF;
   ELSIF upd_flag = 'D'
   THEN
      IF as_cnt = 0
      THEN
         outmsg :=
               'EMPLOYEE ID : '
            || TO_CHAR (inemp_id)
            || ' NOT EXISTS IN EMPLOYEE MASTER';
         outstatus := 'DELETE Failed.';
         RAISE pgm_error;
      END IF;
      UPDATE emp_mst a
         SET a.rec_dtl = rec_dtl (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
       WHERE a.rec_dtl IS NULL;
      UPDATE emp_mst a
         SET a.emp_status_lkp_id = 202,               -- INCATIVE ACCOUNT CODE
             a.rec_dtl.updated_by = inupd_emp_id,
             a.rec_dtl.updated_on = SYSDATE
       WHERE a.emp_id = inemp_id;
      IF SQLCODE <> 0
      THEN
         ROLLBACK;
         outstatus := 'FALSE';
         outmsg := 'DELTE Failed.';
         RAISE pgm_error;
      ELSE
         COMMIT;
         outstatus := 'TRUE';
         outmsg := 'Process sucessfully executed';
      END IF;
   ELSE
      outstatus := 'FALSE';
      outmsg := 'ACTION FLAG SHOULD BE IN I(Insert)/U(Update)/D(Delete).';
      RAISE pgm_error;
   END IF;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('STATUS :' || outstatus || ', MGS :' || outmsg);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN pgm_error
   THEN
      BEGIN
         outstatus := 'FALSE';
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('STATUS :' || outstatus || ', MGS :' || outmsg);
         raise_application_error (-20999, outmsg);
      END;
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      BEGIN
         outmsg := 'INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE FAILED. NO DATA FOUND';
         outstatus := 'FALSE';
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('STATUS :' || outstatus || ', MGS :' || outmsg);
         raise_application_error (-20999, outmsg);
      END;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      BEGIN
         outmsg := 'INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE FAILED. ';
         outstatus := 'FALSE';
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('STATUS :' || outstatus || ', MGS :' || outmsg);
         raise_application_error (-20999, outmsg || SQLERRM);
      END;
END sp_ins_emp_mst_DEV ;
/
```

Comment: You have an unmatched ( or quote somewhere. Use binary search to find the error. Could even be a BEGIN/END ...

Comment: Refactor the code by removing statements until the error disappears. Then you'll know where the syntax error lies.

Comment: Actually this error is most likely to be caused by a missing `end ...` somewhere...

Comment: passed this through 2 beautifiers - both formatted it correctly. Generally beautifiers pickup something missing - are you sure you've posted the right block?

Comment: After creating the tables `emp_mst` and `lookup` and the type `rec_dtl`, I was able to compile your procedure successfully.  If you are getting compilation errors, then you are evidently attempting to compile something other than the procedure above.

Comment: how do you transmit the code you've posted to the server ? is there any software involved that might cut off the data stream ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL*Plus?  If you are, then it's probably the blank lines in your code, which would be interpreted as the end of a line.

I would suggest you do this:

```
set echo on
spool sp_ins_emp_mst_dev.log
<your procedure declaration>
spool off
```

And look very carefully at your line numbers.  If they don't run smoothly from the beginning to the end, try making the blank lines into comments (my choice) or `set sqlblanklines on`.